# Change url in apache

Tags: apache, url, redirect

I have a application running in a standalone server (**brit.sales-01**).
The application is deployed i apache tomcat 6 .Whenever i want to access that application i have to type in the whole address i.e **http:\brit.sales-01.example.com:8185\application**

But i dont want to do that i want when i will type **application.example.com** it should redirect to this application .

Let me know if you need more info from my side
Please help.

Regards
Ab

Answer (score 0):

Putting this rule on your application.example.com server will redirect all traffic to the full port 8185 URL, appending any additional path to the end.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^application.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://brit.sales-01.example.com:8185/application$1 [L]
```